# Git statistics on all files, between two tags

Tags: git

I am just an occasional git user, and now I have a problem that is beyond my knowledge:

Let's say there is a git repository, no branches, just tags. For given two tags. I need to get the list of all files in the reposotory, each followed by two numbers: number of lines added to the particular file between two tags, and number of lines deleted from the same file between the two tags.

I searched online, but I found only solutions for similar problem that deals with contributor, not files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) with the [`--numstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---numstat) option to show "number of added and deleted lines in decimal notation" for each modified file between the two tags.

```
git diff tag1 tag2 --numstat
```

From the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_other_diff_formats):

> The `--numstat` option gives the diffstat(1) information but is designed
>   for easier machine consumption. An entry in `--numstat` output looks
>   like this:
>
> `1    2   README`
>   `3    1   arch/{i386 => x86}/Makefile`
>
> That is, from left to right:
>
> 1. the number of added lines;
> 2. a tab;
> 3. the number of deleted lines;
> 4. a tab;
> 5. pathname (possibly with rename/copy information);
> 6. a newline.

Answer (score 3):

Just run

```
git diff --stat tag1 tag2
```

The files not listed have 0 changes, binary files show `-` as the number of changes.