# Git summary statistics between two tags

Tags: git

I asked a question [Git statistics on all files, between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275423/git-statistics-on-all-files-between-two-tags) some time ago, and got two nice answers.

However, I now need to get how many lines of code is added and deleted between two tags. So, just two numbers, not broken down by files. Obviously, I can run git diff --numstat, and than sum data for all files. But, is there a direct way to get these rwo numbers from git?

Comment: Does `--shortstat` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff --shortstat tag1 tag2
```

[documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---shortstat)